# Rounding in Python

Tags: python-3.x, floating-point, rounding

`round(1.4 999 999 999 999 999)` (without the spaces) gets rounded to 2
but
`round(1.4  99 999 999 999 999)` (without the spaces) gets rounded to 1.

I suppose this has to do with imprecise floating point representations, but fail to understand how does it come that the first representation is interpreted as closer to 2 than to 1.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#tut-fp-issues

Answer (score 5):

Because `1.4 999 999 999 999 999` when parsed is exactly 1.5, the difference between them is too small to represent at that magnitude.

But `1.4  99 999 999 999 999` is low enough to parse to "less than 1.5", actually 1.4999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875, which is clearly less than 1.5

Comment: If this is a general problem, maybe, I could  remove the Python bit from the question.

Comment: It's fairly general, except that the exact semantics of the `round` operation differ from language to language: in Python, `round` is correctly rounded; that's not necessarily going to be true for all languages. OTOH, this is more to do with floating-point representation issues than the rounding operation itself.