# Python 2.7 float rounding

Tags: python-2.7, rounding

I can pick a number close to 0.5 that rounding can gave either 1 or 0.
Why the result of rounding float number is affected by digits far beyond precision?

```
>>> round(0.4999999999999999722444243843710864894092082977294921875)
1.0
>>> round(0.4999999999999999722444243843710864894092082977294921874)
0.0
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37720228/rounding-in-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are *two* rounding steps involved in the line of code:

```
round(0.4999999999999999722444243843710864894092082977294921875)
```

The first step involves converting the decimal string `0.4999999999999999722444243843710864894092082977294921875` (which is not exactly representable as a Python `float`) to the closest value that *is* representable as a Python `float`. Then in the second step, you round that value to the nearest integer. It's the first step that's making a difference here.

The value you've found, `0.4999999999999999722444243843710864894092082977294921875`, is exactly `0.5 - 2**-55`. That's halfway between `0.5` and `0.5 - 2**-54`, both of which are representable in the IEEE 754 binary64 floating-point format that Python uses on the vast majority of machines. The conversion from numeric literal to Python `float` rounds this tie up to `0.5` (following the usual round-ties-to-even rule), and then `round` rounds *that* value up to `1.0` as usual. (Python 2.7 uses the round-ties-away-from-zero rounding mode for `round`, while Python 3 uses round-ties-to-even.)

The second value is a miniscule amount smaller than the first, so it's just slightly closer to `0.5 - 2**-54` than to `0.5`. So the conversion to a Python `float` produces `0.5 - 2**-54`, and then `round` rounds that down to `0.0`, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Round() actually takes in two arguments: the number you want rounded, and the number of significant digits after the decimal point. When you don't add the second argument Python defaults to 0 significant digits. I can't find detailed info on what Python does if the number you want to round is a floating point number and you do not specify a significant digit, but *I suspect it rounds the whole number up or down based on whether your decimal is over or under the amount of significant digits python can handle on your system*.

**In Python floating point numbers have about 53bits of precision available on most computers.**

Here is the official usage for round():

round(number[, ndigits])

Example:

```
round(2.3465, 2)
```

Comment: >In Python floating point numbers have about 53bits So the question is why 56 decimal digits affected?

Comment: "I suspect it rounds the whole number up or down based on whether your decimal is over or under the amount of significant digits python can handle on your system." Nothing so complicated. It rounds the given value to the nearest integer (rounding away from zero in the case of a tie). It's as simple as that.